# How to say “to be stuck with a problem”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

I work at a German company and today I got stuck working on a problem and I am still not done with it. I want to express that to my boss, and I am looking for a word or phrase for being stuck with a problem. For example, how would I say:

> Yesterday I got stuck with fixing the code bug and I am still not done with it.

Comment: Note that the community decided to close your question for the above reason. I narrowed down your question a little bit, hoping that they decide to reopen it, but please see if you can add anything to this, e.g., what you found so far. — I also would like to add that I consider this question sufficiently narrow as it can be answered by a single idiom.

Comment: See http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/what-is-a-phrase-request-and-when-do-we-accept-it-as-on-topic

Answer (score 5):

Consider ***[sich an etwas die Zähne ausbeißen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sich_an_etwas_die_Z%C3%A4hne_ausbei%C3%9Fen)**.* It means that you are failing to solve some problem despite putting a lot of effort in it. Literally, it means *to bite out one’s own teeth.* (I always associated this phrase with gnashing your teeth, but I do not know whether that’s its actual origin.)

Some options for the whole sentence are:

> Ich beiße mir seit gestern an diesem Bug die Zähne aus.
>
> Ich beiße mir seit gestern daran die Zähne aus, diesen Bug zu beseitigen.

Note that using the present tense for *beißen* implies that you are still stuck, so you do not need to explicitly state this.

Comment: Die Übersetzung finde ich unpassend. Sich die Zähne ausbeissen beinhaltet fü mich, dass man es nicht schaffen wird. Stuck with something heisst nicht, dass man nicht irgendwann weiterkommen würde.

Comment: @Robert: Das sehe ich nicht so. Ich würde mich zum Beispiel nicht an folgendem Satz stören: »Erst nachdem ich mir eine Woche an dem Problem die Zähne ausgebissen hatte, bin ich auf die einfache Lösung gestoßen.«

Answer (score 3):

What about: *Ich stecke seit gestern in einem Code-Problem fest und bin immer noch dabei*

Comment: are oyu a native speaker?

Comment: @JackTwain yes. But Anticro's and Wrzlpmft answers are also correct but I tried to follow your wording as exact as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something more formal, or if you are uncomfortable using idioms, I would recommend using something along the lines:

> Die Fehlerbehebung erwies sich als komplizierter als gestern zunächst angenommen. (Daher arbeiten wir auch heute noch an der Lösung.)
>
> Der Fehler hat mich gestern lange aufgehalten und ich habe bis jetzt noch keine Lösung.

Answer (score 1):

Say *Ich bin noch nicht fertig.* If it wasn't the boss you need to talk to, you could also say *Ich habe mich im Code festgebissen.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrases

> an/bei etwas hängen bleiben
>   bei/mit etwas festhängen

can be used in a similar fashion, both along the lines of *to get caught on sth.*, Although I can't give you a rule as to which propositions are appropriate when.

So in your case it would be "Ich hänge seit gestern bei/mit diesem Bug (fest)" or more literally "Ich bin gestern beim Beheben des Code-Bugs hängengeblieben und bin noch immer nicht damit fertig".

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde sagen "Ich suche seit gestern nach einer Lösung für den Bug, habe aber bis heute noch keinen Erfolg gehabt." 
Auch dem Chef gegenüber würde ich da so sagen. 
Wenn er versteht dass Bugs suchen keine Einfache Aufgabe ist wird er dadurch verstehen was Sache ist. Was jedoch nicht heißt das er mit der Situation zu frieden ist... :-)